# Don't checkout branch after rebase in git

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm on my branch (not master) and I need to get the latest version of `master` locally. I do next still staying on my branch:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master master
```

After this `master` is checked out and I need to go back to my branch. Is there any way to avoid the check out local `master` during rebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is unfortunately **no**.

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description) :

> If  is specified, git rebase will perform an automatic git switch  before doing anything else. Otherwise it remains on the current branch.

This is the same for merges : you only work on a checked out branch for these operations, since they theretically *could* result in a conflicting state and would then need to be resolved on the spot.

---

A sort of workaround would be to chain (with `&&` to stop if the rebase returns an error) the subsequent checkout back in an alias.

```
# fm for "fresh master"
git config --global alias.fm '!git fetch && git rebase origin/master master && git checkout -'
```

Comment: Another way to do this without messing with your existing work-tree (and current branch) is to use `git worktree add` to do the rebase.  You can discard the added worktree after the rebase is done.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works most of the time, But if origin/master and master are up to date, the rebase does nothing and using `git checkout -` will put you back in whatever previous branch.

The solution is to check the diff between the two reference before "rebasing".

Also I think we can make it more generic by using an function alias, i.e:

```
refresh = "!f() { \
  git fetch \
  && git diff origin/$1 $1 \
  || { \
        git rebase origin/$1 $1 \
        && git checkout - \
     ;} \
;}; f"
```

*It is easier to define it directly in the config file because the `git config` command will try to escape quote and mess thing up.*

This way you can do `git refresh master` or any other branch. If necessary you can rename the alias with a shorter name or use a double alias to have both, ie:

```
 git config --global alias.rf refresh
```

Good idea for a alias I'll certainly will be using it. Thanks @vitalii

Comment: Oh lol you're right, I just forgot to precede my alias with `!` in the hurry ;-) Editing

Answer (score 0):

If you want the changes to be rebased to your branch, you don't need to checkout `master`. You can stay on your branch and do -

```
git fetch
```

and then

```
git rebase origin/master
```

This will rebase the commits from your local branch on top of the ones from `origin/master`. It won't update your local `master`.

Comment: But I'm afraid OP precisely wanted to rebase `master` *while staying* on his feature branch... (presumably before rebasing the feature on a freshly updated `master`)

Comment: Ah! That was confusing.